# Images in HTML table row

Tags: html, html-table

This has been driving me mad and it's probably the silliest mistake ever!

Basically all I want is each picture to have a small box underneath with their name.
I want 4 pictures, all in a row.

Unfortunately this is what happens in IE:

[image]

I'm so sorry that this looks extremely messy! Any help MUCH appreciated!

```
    <table style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="100%" border-collapse:collapse>
      {section name=signups_loop loop=$signups max=4}


<a href='{$url->url_create("profile",$signups[signups_loop]->user_info.user_username)}'><img src='{$signups[signups_loop]->user_photo("./images/nophoto.gif")}'  width='169' height='172' border='0' vertical-align=bottom></a>



      {cycle name="startrow" values="<tr>,,,,"}

    <td width=201>
<div style="background-color:#809DFF; height: 25px; width: 169px; margin-top: -15px>
<font size="1" face="Tahoma" color="black"><b><div id="feat3">

 <a href='{$url->url_create("profile",$signups[signups_loop]->user_info.user_username)}'><font color="white" face="Tahoma">{$signups[signups_loop]->user_displayname|truncate:15:"...":true}</font></a></b><br></font></font></div>

      </td>
      {cycle name="endrow" values=",,,,</tr>"}
      {/section}</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing the relevant text with the image, inside a container - with a floating left value.

e.g. (bare in mind I did not test this, but hopefully it helps)

```
    <table style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="100%" border-collapse:collapse>
    <tr>
    <td>
    {section name=signups_loop loop=$signups max=4}

      <div class="imageItemWithTextContainer" style="width:169px; float:left; "> <!-- CONTAINER START -->

      <a href='{$url->url_create("profile",$signups[signups_loop]->user_info.user_username)}'><img src='{$signups[signups_loop]->user_photo("./images/nophoto.gif")}'  width='169' height='172' border='0' vertical-align=bottom></a>

      <div style="background-color:#809DFF; height: 25px; width: 169px; margin-top: -15px>
      <font size="1" face="Tahoma" color="black"><b><div id="feat3">

      <a href='{$url->url_create("profile",$signups[signups_loop]->user_info.user_username)}'><font color="white" face="Tahoma">{$signups[signups_loop]->user_displayname|truncate:15:"...":true}</font></a></b><br></font></font></div>

      </div> <!-- CONTAINER END -->

    {/section}
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: It's a step forward! the only thing now is that it's a column instead of a row!

Comment: Okay, I see the <tr><td></td></tr> was not surrounding the table content. See updated answer and let me know if it helps.